# Русский текст в SQLite, UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

При загрузке данных делаю проверку, чтобы не создавать дублей строк. С английским проблем нет, но при проверке русского текста - запрос ничего не выдает и происходит загрузка данных. Как можно решить данную проблему?

```
using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
{
    try
    {
        var temp = objSong.Name_song.Split(new char[] { '.' });
        objSong.Name_song = temp[0];
        var existingsong = conn.Query<Song>("select * from Song where Name_song ='" + objSong.Name_song+"'").FirstOrDefault();
        if (existingsong == null)
        {
            conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                conn.Insert(objSong);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. При изменение запроса к БД, вместо "Query" надо было использовать метод Find.

```
            var existingsong = conn.Find<Tag>(c=>c.Name_song == objTag.Name_song);
            if (existingsong == null)
            {
                conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    conn.Insert(objTag);
                });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]